# Multiple Inheritance and Wrappers in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, wrapper, multiple-inheritance

Apologies for the noob question, but a bit confused by inheritance and wrapper classes in Python and hoping for input.

I'm familiar with this pattern for inheritance in Python:

```
from api.client import Client
from api.wrapper import Wrapper

 
class TestClient(Client):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        Client.__init__(self, wrapper)
 
class TestWrapper(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        Wrapper.__init__(self)

    def updateMktDepth(self, reqId: TickerId, position: int, operation: int,
                side: int, price: float, size: int):
            super().updateMktDepth(reqId, position, operation, side, price, size)
            print("UpdateMarketDepth", "ReqId:", reqId, "Position:", position, "Operation:",
                  operation, "Side:", side, "Price:", price, "Size:", size)
 
    def updateMktDepthL2(self, reqId: TickerId, position: int, marketMaker: str,
            operation: int, side: int, price: float, size: int, isSmartDepth: bool):
        super().updateMktDepthL2(reqId, position, marketMaker, operation, side,
            price, size, isSmartDepth)
        print("UpdateMarketDepthL2", "ReqId:", reqId, "Position:", position, "MarketMaker:", marketMaker, "Operation:",
            operation, "Side:", side, "Price:", price, "Size:", size, "isSmartDepth:", isSmartDepth)
 


def main():

    wrapper = TestWrapper()
    client = TestClient(wrapper)
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 3847, 100)

    print('Connection successful')

    client.disconnect()
```

In follow up, how is `wrapper` passed to instantiate `TestClient` without reference to this parameter in its class definition?  Is this similar/related to the *args/**kwargs mechanism?

I also found this pattern (and class definition for `Client` included as well):

```
from api.client import Client
from api.wrapper import Wrapper
    
class TestApp(Client, Wrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        Client.__init__(self, self)

    def updateMktDepth(self, reqId: TickerId, position: int, operation: int, side: int, price: float, size: int):
        super.updateMktDepth(reqId, position, operation, side, price, size)
        print("UpdateMarketDepth", "ReqId:", reqId, "Position:", position, "Operation:", operation, "Side:", side, "Price:", price, "Size:", size)

    def updateMktDepthL2(self, reqId: TickerId, position: int, marketMaker: str, operation: int, side: int, price: float, size: int, isSmartDepth: bool):
        super.updateMktDepthL2(reqId, position, operation, side, price, size)
        print("UpdateMarketDepthL2", "ReqId:", reqId, "Position:", position, "MarketMaker:", marketMaker, "Operation:", 
              operation, "Side:", side, "Price:", price, "Size:", size, "isSmartDepth:", isSmartDepth)



class Client(object):
    (DISCONNECTED, CONNECTING, CONNECTED, REDIRECT) = range(4)

    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        self.msg_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.wrapper = wrapper
        self.decoder = None
        self.reset()
```

(1)  How does the super operator know where the specified method exists when two base classes are inherited (*note, the method in question exists in only one of the two inherited classes).

(2)  How does the `Client.__init__(self, self)` work to pass the self object twice?  Obviously familiar with passing self, but how does it work to be passed twice?